# Create 3D solid from coordinates (for 3D printing)

Tags: printing, 3d, rendering, autocad, cad

I have got a list of 3D coordinates (x,y,z) and i need to create a .stl file for 3D printer.

Is there any software for this kind of work?

Comment: This site is not for asking for software. Furthermore, the question is very broad.

Comment: Indeed start with just 3D coordinates is very broad... for instance, how are the points connected? Are you planing to use 3-point-faces between them? And which points connects to each point? If the points you have are from a 3D laser scan (point cloud), you can use a mesh to generate the b-rep of the solid, but that's just one case.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged "AutoCAD", so I'm assuming you would be interested with an AutoCAD solution. Using the SubDMesh entity in AutoCAD lets you create a solid from arbitrary points, but as mentioned by our fellows previously, you also need to indicate which point connect to which ones by specifying the faces argument.

```
 if (createSubDMesh)
  {
    Point3dCollection vertarray = new Point3dCollection();
    Int32Collection facearray = new Int32Collection();

    for (i = 0; i < npts; i++)
      vertarray.Add(new Point3d(ptx[i], pty[i], ptz[i]));

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ntri; i++)
    {
      facearray.Add(3);
      facearray.Add(pt1[i]);
      facearray.Add(pt2[i]);
      facearray.Add(pt3[i]);
    }

    SubDMesh sdm = new SubDMesh();
    sdm.SetDatabaseDefaults();
    sdm.SetSubDMesh(vertarray, facearray, 0);
    btr.AppendEntity(sdm);
    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(sdm, true);
  }
```

The sample is extracted from [that post](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/07/triangulating-an-autocad-sub-division-mesh-from-a-set-of-points-using-net.html).

Answer (score 0):

are yo able to draw the file in autocad then you can export that file to .stl format which is compatible with 3D printers

if u have a trouble drawing then explain it